# How to set line break conditions

Tags: javascript, whitespace

`myJson.name.push("         "+"Helooooooooooo");` This is how am printing the data's with white space . But the problem starts when am printing big string  . For Example , `myJson.name.push("         "+"one to three four five six seven eight nine ten");`. My expected output will be

```html
     ' whiteSpace here'one two three four five six seven
                       eight nine ten
```

But my output was ,

```html
'whiteSpac here' one two three four five six seven
eight nine ten
```

I searched in many site's but couldn't get an clear idea . Can someone help\clarify me  .

Comment: You mean the problem is the alignment or the new line? The 2 examples you provide have the same lines, only the text alignment is different. If you have a piece of text already formatted and you want to preserve such format in HTML you should wrap it with the *<pre>* tag.

Comment: Problem is in alignment buddy .If my string print's in the next line mean's i need to add whiteSpace before to them

Comment: You should set the *text-align* of the container tag to *center* than. You don't need to use whitespaces for this.

Comment: Will try that , Thank you .Can i have the Link for that example ? So that i can get some more clarifications.

Comment: Refer this : http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML

Comment: I post an answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed your issue is connected to the text alignment.

Your desired result is to have a centered justification, instead of the normal left justification you got.

To do so, you should change the stylesheet attribute of the container tag to be centered like so:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <!-- your text will go here -->
</div>
```

If you need more styles you should consider to define a class:

```
...
<head>
...
   <style>
   .centered {
        text-align: center;
    }
   </style>
 ...
 </head>
 <body>
 ...
 <div class="centered">
    <!-- your text will go here -->
 </div>
 ...
 </body>
```

If you have to show some already formatted text as it is, you could also use the *<pre>* tag.

```
<per>
Only formatted text here...
     .... it will show as it is ...
... 
</pre>
```

Someone suggested you to use the   to have a whitespace in HTML.

This could be fine for some small spaces separation, to avoid a break.

In case of formatting, is always better to use stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is a entity which can be use to specify a single space.

Use multiple `&nbsp;` to give space as much as you want.

```html
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;one two three four five six seven<br>
eight nine ten
```

Comment: Thanks ,If i use <br> it will print in next line , But in my case it automatically print in next line but i need to add some white spaces to them .

Comment: @SaravanaKumar didn't get you what are you trying to say??

Comment: @GauravAggarwal he needs to add tab before text, not new line.